# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView using ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on my term project which developed on Android device.
The problem is I try to add an object into my ArrayAdapter.
But it gets an errors.

```
11-29 11:58:07.136: D/dalvikvm(1262): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 136K, 8% free 2677K/2880K, paused 30ms, total 32ms

11-29 11:58:07.415: E/ArrayAdapter(1262): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

11-29 11:58:07.415: D/AndroidRuntime(1262): Shutting down VM

11-29 11:58:07.415: W/dalvikvm(1262): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)

11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     ... 40 more
```

This is my MainActivity - **onCreate method.**

```
private EditText createTaskText;
ArrayAdapter<Task> listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // To change body of overridden
                                        // methods use File | Settings |
                                        // File Templates.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // !!! Add quick create task !!!
    createTaskText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quickTopic);
    TextView.OnEditorActionListener exListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && !createTaskText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                // setContentView(R.layout.edit_task_page);
                Intent goTaskEdit = new Intent(ExpandAnimationDemo.this,
                        TaskEdit.class);
                goTaskEdit.putExtra("Topic", createTaskText.getText()
                        .toString());
                startActivity(goTaskEdit);
                createTaskText.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    createTaskText.setOnEditorActionListener(exListener);


    // Creating list, initially = 0 list
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.udiniList);

    Task[] items = {
            new Task("Task 1"),
            new Task("Task 2"),
            new Task("Task 3"),
            new Task("Task 4"),
            new Task("Task 5"),
            };
    // Creating the list adapter and populating the list
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, items);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    // Creating an item click listener, to open/close our toolbar for each
    // item
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {

            View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

            // Creating the expand animation for the item
            ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

            // Start the animation on the toolbar
            toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);

        }
    });

    // !!! Set Swipe to Dismiss !!!
    // Create a ListView-specific touch listener. ListViews are given special treatment because
    // by default they handle touches for their list items... i.e. they're in charge of drawing
    // the pressed state (the list selector), handling list item clicks, etc.
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    list,
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(position));
                            }
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
    list.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    list.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());

}
```

**My Task class**

```
public class Task extends HistoryTask {

int priority;
Calendar duedate;

//------------------------------
// constructors
public Task() {
    duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public Task( String t ) {
    super( t );
    duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public Task( String t, String d ) {
    super( t, d );
    duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public Task( String t, String d, int tg ) {
    super( t, d, tg );
    duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public Task( String t, String d, int tg, int p ) {
    super( t, d, tg );
    priority = p;
    duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public Task( String t, String d, int tg, int p, Calendar dd ) {
    super( t, d, tg );
    priority = p;
    duedate = dd;
}   

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/quickTopic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/quickTaskTopic"
    android:inputType="text" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/udiniList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="20dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/editPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deletePic"
        android:contentDescription="@string/EditDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/pencil" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deletePic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/DeleteDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/delete" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- *********************** -->
<!-- *** TOOLBAR LAYOUT **** -->
<!-- *********************** -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <!-- TextView will showing task details.The details must get from user database -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/Details" />

    <!-- This RelativeLayout manage the TextView which represent the information of Priority, DueDate, and Tag s-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/taskSpec"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <!-- TextView of "Priority" and priority value -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PriorityStr"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/Priority" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PriorityGet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/PriorityStr"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="55dp"
            android:text="@string/SamplePriority" />

        <!-- TextView of "DueDate" and duedate value -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DueDateStr"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PriorityStr"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/DueDate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DueDateGet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PriorityGet"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/DueDateStr"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/SampleDueDate" />

        <!-- TextView of "Tags" and tags value -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TagsStr"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DueDateStr"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/Tags" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TagGet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/DueDateGet"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TagsStr"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:text="@string/SampleTags" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you please share your ExpandAnimation class.

Comment: As logcat said `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
`. So the problem is with instantiation of `ArrayAdapter` not with the code that you have posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it says that `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`

Try changing

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this, R.layout.list_item, items);
```

to this:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.TEXT_VIEW_ID, items);
```

Replace `R.id.TEXT_VIEW_ID` with the TextView id in your layout

Answer (score 1):

Array Adapter takes a xml in the second argument which should contain only a textView. You need to implement your own custom adapter because your `list_item` contains a hell lot of widgets to inflate in a ListView.

Android's ArrayAdapter cannot do that. You need to implement your own by extending ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter

```
11-29 11:58:07.465: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

You are getting this error because your list_item parent Widget is a **`LinearLayout`**, whereas the second argument of a ArrayAdapter takes a **`textview`** xml. For example:

```
        ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 items);
```

If you <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `Click` on `simple_list_item_1`, a xml will open and it will look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

As you can see, it is a single TextView,

So conclusion, you need to implement your own custom adapter.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and your suggestion. I hope your comment is good for other too. ;)